# Are page speed , yslow tools enough to know about website organization and performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I am using pagespeed , yslow to check the no of http requests and website organization for jss,css and images.

we implemented aggregation for js and css files into one js and one css based on the above tools suggestions.

Is there any other things apart from pagespeed and yslow to look at it to take care of website performance issues from HTML ,js , css ,images stand point.

any advices or directions will be really appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps they're not the ULTIMATE tools for determining your site's performance, but they do have a few things that you must consider:

- They we made by huge companies: Google and Yahoo spend millions in research. Is a good thing that they develop tools like these to help developers who heed advice.
- They do a pretty intense checking: If you are using browser's cache and compressing data and all those small tweaks are just the things that make the difference between a slow site and a fast one.

My opinion (which I think is bottom line of what you want: opinions) is that these tools should be taken very seriusly, because they bring lots of adjustments that you should make to your web applications and these adjustments may mark the difference between a few users and lots of them.

Hope I can help!

Comment: thats nice explanation. we do take care of gzip , no of dom elements etc. As there are lot of experts in Stackoverflow , i want to know if there any new techqniques or tips from html,css,jss images stand point. Our backend teams are pretty strong and they care of all performance tuning at the backend.

Answer (score 2):

There will always be little tweaks to add additional speed to your site but following the advice in those tools should be a large percentage of it.

If you've also used image compression (smush it), and moved your js files to the bottom of the page the only thing I would suggest is to stay up to date with new techniques as they emerge.

Comment: @gov Yea, it's great. I've also been minifying all our external js (with a commented copy for editing locally). Between that and using the Google CDN for hosting jQuery itself I have noticed a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to tweak performance from static pages standpoint... YSlow recommendations should be good. You will also benefit if you apply some tweaks from the server standpoint.

Ensure that the static stuff of your web site is neatly categorized so that you can easily apply rules for...

1. Compression of pages, js, css [note that in IIS you will have to manually add other static extensions]
2. Content-Expiry could be additional bonus since if the content is already cached on the client, your server will send just a status code of 304 and your client will pick the file from its IE cache.

Comment: I just found this link and looks like its really useful

Comment: Yeah, you are definitely on the right track. Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not enough. Check out yahoo's boomerang tool to find out how fast your page is loading for end users. It's all well and good making hypothetical improvements, but if you can't monitor how your pages are performing for real users, you're driving blind. You may also consider a distributed performance monitoring tool for the same thing - although nothing beats monitoring performance for actual users.